# Wizard - "Start Over" buttons

Tags: jquery, wizard

I have created my "wizard" and I have it working the way I need it to but my question is how to I create a "Start Over" button on the results pages that will clear all radio buttons and display the starting div?

Currently I have the same button inside 2 results divs, but only the first one works. Help! (Select "Question 1 - Answer 1" then "Question 2 - Answer 1 OR 2" to get to what I am talking about.)

http://jsfiddle.net/dswinson/PXp7c/56/

Also if you have another idea on how I can implement this wizard that is easier please let me know.

Comment: Your code makes me wish you knew what [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) is

Comment: @Raynos: It makes a nice pattern though :-) In all seriousness (@OP), using functions and other stuff to not repeat yourself is incredibly handy!

Comment: Well I'm not very fluent in this type of programming and this is like a tree of questions and answers. So answer 1 can take you to question 3 but answer 2 can take you to question 4 (if that makes any sense) and it goes on and on that way. I have been trying to find a way to build this out and this is the only way I could come up with.

Comment: Is there any way to clean this code up? I'm pretty new this.

Answer (score 2):

As you probably read from the comments, your script is little bit [wrong](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrjwaqZfjIY). This way of programming is not dynamic in any way..it might work on some level, but as you probably already experienced its horrible to maintain.

For such applications you need to make a core-plugin that handles some sort of an array, that contains the questions and answers. This seemed like an interesting challenge, so I created a plugin, that is based on your examples parameters. Its called **DawnWizard**.

I hope, that understand the general concept of this plugin and will apply the same methods on your next projects :)

```
/*
 * DawnWizard v1.0
 * Originally made for Dawn's question in StackOverflow
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378814/
 * 
 * Made by Kalle H. Väravas
 * http://stackoverflow.com/users/721553/
 * 
 * No direct copyright or licences.
 * Use however you want, just give me lots of +1 :)
*/
(function ($) {
    $.fn.exists = function () {return $(this).length > 0;}
    $.fn.DawnWizard = function (input_setup) {
        var default_setup = {
            title: 'Demo wizard',
            description: 'Welcome text..'
        };
        setup = jQuery.extend(default_setup, input_setup || {});
        var wizard_container = $(this);
        var questions_count = 0;
        jQuery.each(setup['questions'], function () {
            questions_count++;
        });
        load_startup = function () {
            results = [];
            wizard_container.empty().append(
                $('<h1>').html(setup['wizard']['title']),
                content_container = $('<div id="content">').append(
                    $('<p>').html(setup['wizard']['description']),
                    $('<button id="start_wizard" />').text('Start the Wizard')
                )
            );
            $('#start_wizard').click(function () {
                load_question(current_qid = 1);
            });
        };
        load_results = function () {
            content_container.empty().append(results_container = $('<p>'));
            jQuery.each(setup['questions'], function (i, question) {
                results_container.append($('<div>').text(explain_qid(i) + ' - ' + results[i]));
            });
            content_container.after($('<button id="start_over">').text('Start over'));
            current_qid = 1;
            $('#start_over').click(function () {
                load_startup(current_qid = 1);
            });
        };
        load_question = function (qid) {
            if (qid == 0) {
                load_startup();
                return;
            } else if (qid == questions_count + 1) {
                load_results();
                return;
            }
            content_container.empty().append(
                $('<p>').append(
                    $('<b id="question">').html(setup['questions'][qid]['question']),
                    questions = $('<ul>')
                ),
                $('<button id="previous">').text('Previous'),
                $('<button id="next">').text('Next')
            );
            jQuery.each(setup['questions'][qid]['answers'], function (i, answer) {
                questions.append($('<li><input type="radio" name="answer" value="' + answer + '"> ' + answer + '</li>'));
            });
            $('#previous, #next').click(function () {
                var action =  $(this).attr('id');
                var checked_answer = $('input[name=answer]:checked');
                if (action == 'previous') {
                    load_question(current_qid = current_qid - 1);
                } else if (action == 'next') {
                    if (checked_answer.size() > 0) {
                        insert_result(current_qid, checked_answer.val());
                        load_question(current_qid = current_qid + 1);
                    } else {
                        add_message('You forgot to check an answer!', 'error');
                    }
                }
            });
        };
        insert_result = function (qid, answer) {
            results[qid] = answer;
        };
        explain_qid = function (qid) {
            return setup['questions'][qid]['question'];
        };
        add_message = function (message, type) {
            if (jQuery.inArray(type, ['error', 'success'])) {
                return;
            }
            if (!$('#message').exists()) {
                content_container.before(
                    $('<div id="message" class="' + type + '">')
                    .text(message)
                    .fadeIn()
                    .delay(2000)
                    .fadeOut('normal', function () {
                         $(this).remove();
                     })
                );
            }
        };
        load_startup();
    };
}) (jQuery);
```

<sup>**[ [View output](http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/9pfME/) - [Commented version](http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/9pfME/1/) ]**</sup>

**How to set the questions and answers, calling it:**

```
$('#put_wizard_here').DawnWizard({
    wizard: {
        title: 'Demo wizard',
        description: 'Welcome text..'
    },
    questions: {
        1: {
            question: 'Who is hotter?',
            answers: [
                'Miley', 'Selena', 'Mila'
            ]
        },
        2: {
            question: 'Who is the smartest?',
            answers: [
                'Kalle H. Väravas', 'Kalle\'s colleague'
            ]
        },
        3: {
            question: 'Coolest StackExchange?',
            answers: [
                'StackOverflow', 'Programmers', 'Gaming'
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

<sup>**[ [View output](http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/9pfME/) - [Commented version](http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/9pfME/1/) ]**</sup>

Comment: Been working on this since June? :) Nice work though, and great of you to comment everything so OP can learn something rather than just get a handout.

Comment: @Wesley, I like to work on old questions -- no race-pressure^^ Also, maybe get some badges and new knowledge while doing it..  But thanks for the upvote :) I wasn't sure if using object arrays, was the most optimal way.. but I tested every other concepts, and this seems to be most efficient way.